# Let $(C, \otimes, \alpha, 1, l, r)$ be a monoidal category. Show that $l_{1 \otimes A} = id_1 \otimes l_A$ and $r_{A \otimes 1} = r_A \otimes id_1$.

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $(C, \otimes, \alpha, 1, l, r)$ be a monoidal category. I would like to show that

> for any object $A$ in $C$ the equalities $l_{1 \otimes A} = id_1 \otimes l_A$ and $r_{A \otimes 1} = r_A \otimes id_1$ hold true.

A hint tells me that one should use functoriality of the left and right unitor $l$ and $r$, but I do not understand what this means in this case. I am probably missing the definition of a functorial isomorphism. Can someone help me to prove the above identities ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't $\mathrm{id}_A: A \to A$ and $l_A: 1 \otimes A \to A$, so $\mathrm{id}_A \otimes l_A : A \otimes (1 \otimes A) \to A \otimes A$, while $l_{1 \otimes A}: 1 \otimes (1 \otimes A) \to 1 \otimes A$, so this has no hope of being true. I could well be misunderstanding though...

Comment: @B.Mehta You are right. I think It should be $id_1$ instead $id_A$.

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$l_A : 1\otimes A\cong A$ is *natural* in $A$. That means the following is a naturality square: $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1\otimes (1\otimes A) @>id_1\otimes l_A>> 1\otimes A \\
@Vl_{1\otimes A}VV @VVl_AV \\
1\otimes A @>>l_A>  A
\end{CD}$$ That is, $l_A\circ (id_1\otimes l_A) = l_A\circ l_{1\otimes A}$ to which we post-compose with $l_A^{-1}$ to get $id_1\otimes l_A = l_{1\otimes A}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :). I see that the proof of the second equality is completely analogous.